# Problem with \caps (from soul package) in header using memoir

Tags: header-footer, memoir, soul

I am publishing my 3rd book with LaTeX. There was a long hiatus between the second book and the third, but evidently something has changed that has broken my header format. When I attempt to re-LaTeX my old files---the files used to create production PDFs of previous books---an error occurs that never occurred earlier.

I am using the soul package for better treatment of all-cap text, which I put in the page headings. For some reason the "\caps" control sequence is causing MikTeX to throw the following error: "Argument of \@uclcnotmath has an extra }"

Below is a minimal example. If I remove the "\caps" from the heading definition, the error goes away.

Any advice on how to fix this? My previous books were done about 5 years ago. I have no idea why this is no longer working.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,openright, onecolumn, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{soul}

\makepagestyle{headings}
\makeevenhead{headings}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{\caps\rightmark}
\makepsmarks{headings}{%
\createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{}{}
\def\sectionmark##1{
\markright{##1}}}

\pagestyle{headings}

\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}

This is page 1

\eject

This is page 2

\eject

This is page 3

\end{document}
```

Comment: try changing to `\def\sectionmark##1{
\markright{\caps{##1}}}}` and `\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{\rightmark}`. `soul`-package documentation lists some stuff that won't work under section 2.2 in its documentation, **§ 24 Material that needs expansion**.

Comment: What exactly does the `\caps` macro for, that is different from using `\nouppercaseheads ` and then use `\scshape\rightmark`. You might even get better results via the features from the  microtype package (soul is a bit limited)

Comment: daleif, soul has different spacing rules than vanilla scshape. I use microtype in my manuscript in general but did not look into its specific features.

Comment: @RunarTrollet Thanks! That worked great, both on my repro and the whole manuscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is due to the way that `soul`-package does its expansions, which won't work with `\rightmark`.

From the documentation, section **2.2.** [Some things work…] **…others don't**:

> **§ 24 Material that needs expansion:**
>
> Example: `\so{\romannumeral\year}`
>
> In this example `\so` would try to put space between `\romannumeral` and `\year`, which can, of course, not work. You have to expand the argument before you feed it to soul, or even better: Wrap the material up in a com- mand sequence and let soul expand it: `\def\x{\romannumeral\year} \so\x`. soul tries hard to expand enough, yet not too much.

We can circumvent this by instead putting it into your definiton of `\sectionmark`:

```
\def\sectionmark##1{\markright{\caps{##1}}}}
```

since this will exand correctly,
and removing the `\caps{}` from your `\makeoddhead`.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[a5paper,openright, onecolumn, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{soul}

\makepagestyle{headings}
\makeevenhead{headings}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{headings}{}{}{\rightmark}
\makepsmarks{headings}{%
\createmark{chapter}{both}{nonumber}{}{}
\def\sectionmark##1{\markright{\caps{##1}}}}

\pagestyle{headings}

\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}

This is page 1

\eject

This is page 2

\eject

This is page 3

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do wonder why it worked earlier (in 2011, when I published my earlier manuscript using the same code).  It seems that the soul package was last changed in 2003...

Comment: I do not know. Haven't really been using `LaTeX` for more than a year, but maybe `memoir` have changed. Just guesswork really,